# Why are these collections not equal?

Tags: apex, list, collection

I am currently working on the list concepts of apex and working on this piece of code:

```
List<Integer> ages = New List<Integer>();
ages.add(10);
ages.add(20);
List<Integer> one = New List<Integer>();
ages.add(10);
ages.add(20);
Boolean b = ages.equals(one);
system.debug('Equals: ' +b);
```

My expectation for the debug should be

> true

true. However, when I check it - I am getting

> false

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Considering you posted a question on this site tagged with Apex in 2016, it is untruthful to say you are new to development. Even if it were true, it would still be completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lists are not equal; you added four values to `ages`, and none to `one`. It looks like you meant to do this:

```
List<Integer> ages = New List<Integer>();
ages.add(10);
ages.add(20);
List<Integer> one = New List<Integer>();
one.add(10);
one.add(20);
Boolean b = ages.equals(one);
system.debug('Equals: ' +b);
```

Comment: @abhi If this answer works for you please remember to "accept" it by selecting the check mark next to the answer. This way, other uses with similar questions will know which answer was correct.